# STM32CubeMX USB error "Unknown USB Device(Descriptor Request Failed)"

Tags: usb, pcb-design, stm32

My STM32 project has an issue about VCP on a CubeMX generated project.

When the USB cable is plugged in, the windows10 can't recognise it and in the device manager panel, it says "Unknown USB Device(Descriptor Request Failed), error code 43". The funny thing is after the  USB cable been plugged in and out several times (usually more than 10 times), windows suddenly can recognize it. After that, if I power off the board for a short time(several seconds), the USB can always be recognized successfully by windows even if it is plugged out and in repeatedly; but if I shut down the board for a long time, then the issue will arise again.

I've taken the following steps to debug it but no effect:

- I build a simple project on CubeMX with just OTG_FS, this issue is still existing.
- I've also tried to enable/disable VBUS sensing function but it's the same.
- I've measured the voltage on DP and VBUS which are 2.8v/4.4v when this issue exists.

I can't think of another method to debug this issue. Any ideas or suggestions about solving this issue is welcome. Thank you!

These are information related to the USB in my project:

The chip is STM32F205VGT, cubeMX version is 5.0.1.

Keil version:

[image]

USB configration:

[image]

[image]

Clock:

[image]

Schematic and PCB, the board is powered from wall supply rather than VBUS:

[image]

[image]

Updated:

Finally, the issue is fixed by resoldering the 16MHz crystal which may not contact well enough in the first version.

Comment: Screenshots don't constitute code, nor have you provided the circuitry around the MCU itself.  Might be worth temporarily adapting it to bus power to reduce variables.

Comment: @ChrisStratton To avoid code error, the simple project is all generated with CubeMX, I don't write a single line code.

Comment: If you're going to develop by point and click, post only screenshots, *and omit schematics* you don't have an answerable question on an SE site.  Perhaps ST support will help you.

Comment: Why use HSI RC for USB clock source while HSE is the clock source for everything else? Also, why directly connect the resistor from 3V3 to DP? It will tell PC to start enumeration when MCU gets power, not when the MCU firmware is ready to enumerate.

Comment: One problematic thing is that the R34 pull-up must be engaged only after VBUS is applied (cable plugged into host). If your MCU is not ready for some reason (still booting, USB code is confused by something), windows will try to enumerate your device prematurely, and will fail. You need to make the R34 pull-up conditional with the VBUS, and enable it only when your code is ready.

Comment: Also "activate VBUS" looks like a wrong function; it means that you are making OTG. If OTG, then there must be ID input. What the input is doing currently?

Comment: @Ale..chenski Thanks for replying.I've done an experiment which I remove the R34 pull-up and then the USB cable is plugged into the host and wait for 5~10 seconds for STM32 to finish booting. Then I manually connect the DP and 3V3 with a wire. However, the issue is still existing.

Comment: The OTG code must use an input from ID pin. I asked, what the ID input is doing? If it is floating, the code may perform erratically.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I just unselect the "Active VBUS" option, but the issue still exists. Currently, I use the device only mode.

Comment: Finally, I find the reason leading to this issue. It's the crystal oscillator pseudo soldering. When I switch the clock source to HSI, the USB connection build successfully. Next step, I will resolder the crystal oscillator to provide a reliable clock to STM32.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The issue was the stability and accuracy of the oscillator that was out of specs for USB. The PC detected the USB device but reported an unknown descriptor or a "bad usb device". The internal oscillator may be too inaccurate for USB to function properly. And an external chip has to be selected with care and USB requirements in mind.

Comment: Answers (even random ones) belong in the answer box, not as edits to the question, otherwise this will never show as resolved.

Comment: @Ross:  Since you found it, would you please post an answer and explain how you figured it out?  You can then accept the answer, and leave things nice and tidy.

Comment: As JRE says, Ross please post resoldering the 16MHz crystal as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When I switch the clock source to HSI, the USB connection build successfully, so the reason may be the poor quality of crystal oscillator or bad soldering. I resolder the crystal oscillator and this time the USB can get connected with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after some headaches, I realized that the nucleo board I was using has the clock coming from the st-link locked in at 8MHz. CubeMX default settings had it set to 25MHz for me. Switching HSE to 8MHz (bypass mode) did the trick!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed input frequency of HSE from 16 Mhz to 8 Mhz and it helped.

[image: Screenshot:]